# pipenv stucks while creating a venv

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv, pipfile

I'm trying to create a venv for an already-created project on my computer. The project has a pipfile. When I try to create the venv using `pipenv sync` or `pipenv shell` it stucks forever. When I hit Ctrl+C it shows the following:

```
^CEnvironment creation aborted.
Error:  An error occurred while removing /home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/dbm-9yn1B79h!
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/dbm-9yn1B79h'
```

I'm on WSL. Several other projects with a very similar structure are working fine.
I tried removing and re-cloning the project several times. I checked the ownerships. I tried re-installing `pipenv`.
Yet the venv fails to be created.

Comment: The error message is probably from cleanup code for the ctrl+c action.  It seems it catches the ctl+c and puts out the aborted message.  the other stuff is it probably trying to do some cleanup..

Comment: did you try the -v flag for verbose mode?

Comment: @LhasaDad trying with -v does not make any difference

Comment: I wonder if its pip just trying to resolve the dependencies and struggling to do it.  can you create a venv and then use pip with that activated in verbose mode to see if maybe its pip trying to find a solution of packages of the right version that is the issue?  just a thought.

Comment: I understood that venv cannot be created for this specific project using pipenv. I clearly does not reach the point of installing libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by adding a `.env` file to the project containing `PYTHONPATH=.`